# Delete elements from dom with library PDF2DOM

Tags: java

I have this code in Java that converts a pdf to html and returns it to me in a JAX-RS web service, I have used the PDF2DOM library to do it. I would like to know if there is a way to access the div that the r class creates for me and delete them, since they make the document not display well in HTML. Or, failing that, delete the style called r from the header.

```
Document dom = null;
try {
    // load the PDF file using PDFBox
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(tempFile);
    // create the DOM parser
    PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
    // parse the file and get the DOM Document
    dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return dom;
```

[PDF2DOM](https://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve the question with this code:

```
File tempFile = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    tempFile = File.createTempFile("tmp", dr.getId(), null);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    fos.write(dr.getContent().get(0).getAttachment().getData());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Document dom = null;
try {

    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(tempFile);
    PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
    dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);

    NodeList myDivs = dom.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (int i = 0; i < myDivs.getLength(); i++) {
        NamedNodeMap myMap = myDivs.item(i).getAttributes();
        for (int j = 0; j < myMap.getLength(); j++) {

            String nodeType = myMap.item(j).getNodeName();
            String nodeClass = myMap.item(j).getNodeValue();
            if (nodeType.compareTo("class") == 0 && nodeClass.compareTo("r") == 0) {
                myMap.removeNamedItem(myMap.item(j).getNodeName());
            }

        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return dom;
```